# ora-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource - PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I'm trying to call a function with a database link and get the following error: ora-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource. I'm using PL/SQL to write my code on the database.

How can I avoid this error? Committing the after-calling function is impossible because it is a sensitive process where many things happen after the called function.

Trying to resolve the problem

Comment: For deadlocks, the error message itself is not sufficient information for troubleshooting. Look on the database for a trace file that was generated at the same time as the error. That file will provide the two relevant SQL statements and objects. Without that information you can only guess at the problem and solution. I'm not sure if the trace file will be generated in the source database or the target database, so you might need to ask a DBA to check both.